# multiple image upload used two time in page but the first is working another is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

Multiple image upload used in two time in single page First image upload is proper working second is not working i tried but its not fixed with preview and delete option using jquery.But Both are shown in separate area first images uplad shown in below of first and second is shown in below of second jsfiddle code is below in comment

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Baloch007/4jy9qbom/4/

Comment: When you use multiple DOM element, instead of the ID, use a class to get them like class="upload_input" and apply your JS to all elements (handled by jQuery).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just write:

```
// edit the change event 
$('input:file').change(function(evt){
    handleFileSelect(evt);
});
```

Comment: i **Dont understand** Dear Dhara if you dont mind please help me in js fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Baloch007/4jy9qbom/4/

Comment: Brother the images display both are separate area . The First image upload are shown images in below of first and separate. The second is also separate and show in below of second image upload.Thanks

Comment: Brother you have mentioned above the issue of image upload only :) you have not mentioned the alignment issue above.. thanks :)

Comment: **Dhara Parmar** help me please i dont understand the code because i am a new. Thanks

Comment: I have updated the code for image display issue in this jsfiddle. try this: https://jsfiddle.net/rme2er5a/

Comment: brother image shown in separate areas thanks for this but second image upload shown but delete function are  not working Thanks

Comment: i am very thankful to you my dear **Dhara Parmar** .You and your attitude was great and you are a great man if you dont mind would you like to friendship with me if you say yes then its my facebook id **muhammadirfan007007@gmail.com** Thanks My dear Brother

Answer (score 0):

You must change your ids. They should be different. Like change your second "**input[type=file]'s id**  and **output's id**".

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="first-uploader">
<input type="file" id="files" name="image_file_arr[]" multiple>
<br><output id="list"></output>
</div>
<div class="second-uploader">
<input type="file" id="files1" name="image_file_arr[]" multiple>
<br><output id="list1"></output>
</div>

var count=0;
    function handleFileSelect(evt,id) {
        var $fileUpload = $("input#files[type='file']");
        count=count+parseInt($fileUpload.get(0).files.length);

        if (parseInt($fileUpload.get(0).files.length) > 6 || count>5) {
            alert("You can only upload a maximum of 5 files");
            count=count-parseInt($fileUpload.get(0).files.length);
            evt.preventDefault();
            evt.stopPropagation();
            return false;
        }
        var files = evt.target.files;
        for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
            if (!f.type.match('image.*')) {
                continue;
            }
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = (function (theFile) {
                return function (e) {
                    var span = document.createElement('span');
                    span.innerHTML = ['<img class="thumb" src="', e.target.result, '" title="', escape(theFile.name), '"/><span class="remove_img_preview"></span>'].join('');
                    document.getElementById(id).insertBefore(span, null);
                };
            })(f);

            reader.readAsDataURL(f);
        }
    }

    $('#files').change(function(evt){
        handleFileSelect(evt,'list');
    });
  $('#files1').change(function(evt){
        handleFileSelect(evt,'list1');
    });

    $('#list').on('click', '.remove_img_preview',function () {
        $(this).parent('span').remove();

        //this is not working...
        var i = array.indexOf($(this));
        if(i != -1) {
            array.splice(i, 1);
        }
        // tried this too:
        //$(this).parent('span').splice( 1, 1 );

        count--;
    });
```

Try this, it works

Comment: Brother its shown in separate area thanks for this But second image upload delete option are not working Thanks

Comment: $('#list, #list1').on('click', '.remove_img_preview',function () {}); Add this it will work